# Dynamic Load Debug vs Release Native Libraries In Java with Debug Postfix

Tags: java, c++, windows, dll

On windows, native DLLs are sometimes built such that the debug versions have a 'd' postfix on them: Mylibd.dll vs MyLib.dll (Boost does this as an example).

How does one go about dynamically loading these libraries with System.load or System.LoadLibrary correctly in Java? I have seen these types of issues typically overcome by having the build process compile an alternate copy of the Java source file that has the other lib name since there is no preprocessor. I would like to avoid this if possible (to me it needlessly complicates the build and duplicates source files).

I also don't want to try and load both (one as a fallback): I want my release version to load only the release version and debug only debug.

A little background and motivations: I have a CMake build that builds our entire stack: native C++ libs, Java SWIG wrapper, and .NET wrappers, for multiple configurations (Debug, Release, etc). So I get a complete different build for each configuration. We only ship the release version of the Java wrapper but for debugging I would like to load the debug libraries correctly that have the 'd' postfix.

Currently, we just build the debug/release JNI DLL versions to have the same name. However, this breaks the pattern for how we build our other native DLLs, which have the 'd' postfix for debug. We actually ship the debug versions of those libs because they have C++ in the API that require the dynamic C runtime. So I would like the JNI DLLs to look as closely as possible to the other artifacts of the build.

Comment: Have you considered using `java.util.Properties` and a properties file to store the name of the DLL to load?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Don't really want to have an additional file along side the JAR at runtime, seems pretty overkill, especially for something like debugging. I'd rather hack together the build process so that I don't have to worry about more files on the filesystem and a runtime depends.

Comment: A VERY awful hack is to patch the binary class file which contains the DLL name as a string.

Comment: @manuell yes, awful indeed. And I would have to by default put the debug version in the source file and then edit the class file for the release version name since there isn’t enough room to go from release -> debug lib name (1 character longer).

Comment: You want awful? I deliver awful! In the Java file, let the DLL file name be string of 100 characters '$'. When patching, search that string and replace it with whatever DLL file name you want (padding to 100 with null bytes). Yes, I actually do that in production code, at Run Time. Please don't ask.